# Adding Integer to the ASCII value of a character

Tags: c, char, ascii

For example I have the char `a` which has an ASCII value of 97 and I want to add 10 to that ASCII value but save it again as the letter `k` in that case. How can I do that?

(I'd like to give a code example but I don't have one.)

Comment: Literally just `'a' + 10`.

Comment: I don't mean to be offensive, but if you wanted to add 10, why did you not just try to add 10?

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between `97` and `'a'`; they both produce the integer ninety-seven. The following two lines are equivalent:

```
char ch = 97;
char ch = 'a';
```

How do you add ten to a number? Using the addition operator or `+=`.

```
ch += 10;
```

The following would therefore produce `k`:

```
printf("%c\n", ch);
```

This will output a byte with a value of 117, which your terminal or editor or whatnot will interpret as `k`.

---

Caveat: This answer presumes an ASCII-based machine. `'a'` wouldn't be equivalent to `97` on an EBCDIC-based machine. Also, letters aren't consecutive in [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC), so adding `'a' + 10` wouldn't get you `'k'`.

Comment: Well that was easier than expectet

Answer (score 1):

Just add 10 to it.

```c
char letter = 97;
letter += 10;

printf("%c\n", letter);
```